# in nifi, how to call an external program that ask an input file and an output file in parameters

Tags: apache-nifi

I have an external program, an ebook converter, to convert .epub to .txt. 
This converter requests a file as input and another file as output, the filenames are important here because the extension is used to determine which conversion should be made, also from what I saw while testing, the program is performing seeks on the input file. So those contrains prenvents usage of named pipes or SDTIN redirections.

For another project, or at least a POC, I'll have to encapsulated an existing bundle of tools that are working the same way as above and recreate the workflows bettween in Nifi.

In short term, writing a custom processor is not possible.

So how should i do it ?

here are a couple of possible solutions I found :

- create a PutFile processor who will put the file in a temporary location, chain it with an executeStreamCommand who will execute the external command and put the output in a temporary location and chain it with a fetchFileProcessor. But the issue here may be that I have to found a way to clean the temporary files.
- another solution would be to create a script to use with ExecuteScript to do something like : write the flowfile to disk with filename based on attributes, executute the external command, read the outputfile to the flowfile and perform some cleaning. but from what I found, it's not that easy to write to disk from this processor, right ?

so what direction should I go, any advices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.  I think you could do a sequence of processors like the following:

1. [UpdateAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/index.html) - create attributes for the input and output file names.
2. [PutFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutFile/index.html) - write the temp input file.
3. [ExecuteProcess](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0./org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteProcess/index.html) - run the conversion utility.  I recommend wrapping this in a shell script, which gives you an opportunity to clean up the temp input file when it completes.
4. [FetchFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFile/index.html) - read the conversion output into the FlowFile content. Use `Completion Strategy` of `Delete File` to clean up the converted file.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I ended with, I just added a second `FetchFile` in oputput of `ExecuteProcess` with 
`Completion Strategy` set to `Delete File` to also clean the temp input file

Comment: This no longer seems to work (Nifi 1.6.0) - or at least won't work in a chain - as `ExecuteProcess` is tagged "source" and won't accept an inbound link. `ExecuteStreamCommand` _may_ work in this situation.